# Mindstorms nxt screen not lighting up

Tags: mindstorms, nxt

I just pickup up this set at a garage sale and put in new batteries.  The initial start up noises were indicated and there are clicking noises but the screen is not lighting up.  Is it broken or do I just need to install the software?